# Floating CSS image over backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make a custom CSS webpage, but I'm having difficulty getting all the pictures to show unless I make the min-height around 900px. The index code looks like this,

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("stylesheets/mystyle.css");
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Small Biz Labs</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="conatiner" align="center">
                <div class="header">
                    <center>
                        <img src="images/logo.png" width="200" height="100" />
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>Maybe a header</h1>
                    <p>some text</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

and the CSS code looks like this...

```
/* 
Document   : mystyle
Created on : Jul 18, 2012, 1:12:14 PM
Author     : someguy
Description:
    Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/

html {
background:url(../images/bodybackground.jpg) repeat;
margin:0px;
max-height:100%
}

body {
background:url(../images/paperbackground.jpg) repeat-y center;
margin:0px;
margin:0px;
max-height:100%;

}


.wrap {
background:url(../images/new_backdrop.png) repeat-x center bottom fixed;
margin:0px;
min-height:1050px;
}


.container { 
max-width:600px;

}

.header {
}

.text {
text-align:left;
max-width:600px;
padding-left:10px;
}
```

I'm trying to get the bottles to float over the two textures I made. Allowing for text/images etc. to be placed in the smaller lighter version of the paper texture. So far I can only make this happen if I set the max-height large enough. Any suggestions on how to adjust my code?
The images I'm using can't be posted until I get more points, but if you want to see them let me know and ill shoot you the jpgs and the one png (the one that floats).

If you want to see a semi live [version](http://smallbizlabs.net/bizlabs/)
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wKtGv/

Comment: Im having a hard time understanding what you want. From the link you posted, it looks like you have achieved it to my understanding of your question.

Comment: It only looks fine because of the min-height is so large, when i lower it to the images real size, it gets cut off, the real size of the image is at http://smallbizlabs.net/bizlabs/images/new_backdrop.png i want it to be dynamic, so that's why i repeat-x, but its like its being pushed down by a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height:100%; to both body and .wrap
http://jsfiddle.net/wKtGv/13/

Comment: When i added the 100% it still works fine, but the bottles image is about 500px high, but when i try to set this as the min-height, it cuts off the top of the image. I used your http://jsfiddle.net/wKtGv/13/ and just adjusted in html from 5000px to 500, and set the min height of wrap to 500px, then it cuts of my image. Any suggestions on what to do with the floating image to get it be default to the bottom and be the minimum height?  Thanks for the reponses so far!